# Building Ruby on Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment

Has anyone out there got a good set of instructions for building/compiling Ruby from source of windows XP ?

Comment: See update - try out the steps and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/184380

I normally get a binary installable for windows.. much faster if you just need Ruby installed. But you may be modifying ruby source.. anyways..

**Update:** I ended up compiling Ruby from source today... here is what worked for me
http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html

Answer (score 2):

[Luis Lavena](http://blog.mmediasys.com/) maintains the Ruby One-Click installer binaries. His blogs and postings on Ruby Forum are definitely the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that the binary distrubtion is your best bet for Ruby on Windows, however, like Gishu mentioned, you may be modifying it a bit.  If that's the case I would build it from source with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  This will give you the familiar tool set for building software from source.

However [the following thread at Ruby Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/58141) seems to have a very active discussion on building Ruby in Windows using Microsoft's Visual C++ toolkit with some other .NET additions.

Good luck!