# Error: Error installing spork: The 'spork' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started work with Ruby on Rails in about two weeks ago and now im having a problem with SPORK. i can´t start the server because its sayin that The 'spork' native gem requires installed build tools and saying to update your PATH to include buil, tools od donwload the DevKit.

I dont know how to fixed that, im using ruby 1.8.7 on rails 2.3.9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile ruby from source. This is really not as scary as it seems.

The easiest method for doing this is using RVM. RVM will download the desired ruby source and compile automatically. Unfortunately RVM is *NIX dependent. For windows look at [Building Ruby on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107173/building-ruby-on-windows-xp).

The rvm command would be something like:

rvm install 1.8.7

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

**Note**: You will have to reinstall any gems your app is dependent on once you get ruby installed through RVM. However, you can swtich between your rvm ruby, and your system ruby at any time.

EDIT: RVM is not platform independent, my bad.

Comment: -1 How do you expect him to compile Ruby if he doesn't have build tools?

Comment: @Rein When you use rvm to install ruby it includes build tools. (and builds ruby from source) as part of the process. If you want to download build tools and ruby source manually and go that route, all the better.

Comment: Er. rvm does not install a compiler for you.

Comment: Your right, my bad. However, you will get the no build tools error even if you do have build tools on your system, at least with the gems I have seen.

Comment: thanks, i did just like you said, and  worked perfectly. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need build tools (the ability to compile) to install gems with native extensions. For more info, please tell us what platform you are on.